# Update the tableView - without refresh completely

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created the table "tableView" (data from CoreData - NSManagedObject). I want to update the data in the tables when the new notification comes from NSNotification without refreshing the table completely. How to do it ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to back tableview with autoupdating results from CoreData then its best to use NSFetchedResultsController.  Apple has sample code on how to do this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html).

The sort version is you implement the delegate methods for willChangeContent and didChangeContent and forward the relevant changes (ie insert, delete and reload row) to the tableView, and this will keep your tableview in synch with your database.

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .move:
        break
    case .update:
        break
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .move:
        tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Data from CoreData will be loaded only once. The table is to be updated when notification from NSNotification comes. But thank you for the example will be useful in the future.